# Java Zkoss Frontend Framework - Break line in property label

Tags: java, string, properties, xhtml, zk

I invested too much time, now I want to ask you how can I insert a line break at a specific position in the value of a .properties file-property. for example, I have:

**the zul:**

```
<zk xmlns:h="native" xmlns:x="xhtml">
  <groupbox width="850px">
    <caption label="${c:l('not this label')}" />
    <h:table >
      <h:tr>
        <h:td>
          <h:label>${c:l('mylabel.linebreakedlabel')}</h:label>
        </h:td>
....
```

**the .properties file:**

```
mylabel.linebreakedlabel = Hello this label should be breaked into two lines
```

---

I tried many different solutions:

A:

```
Hello this label should be \  breaked
into two lines
-> second line in label gets thrown away
```

B:

```
{
Hello
second line
}
-> The {} gets rendered and second line is thrown away
```

C:

```
\n with and without enter either renders the sign or throws away the whole second line
```

D:

```
Tried </br>, the element itself gets rendered
```

Im asking on this platform because ZK Forums won't send me an email to confirm my register.
Anyone knows the problem or atleast know where the problem lies?  (Using ZK Version 6)

Thank you!

Comment: Regarding forum registration issue, please email to info@zkoss.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please read [Specify a Value with Multiple Lines](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Internationalization/Labels/The_Format_of_Properties_Files#Specify_a_Value_with_Multiple_Lines), [its code example](https://github.com/zkoss/zkbooks/blob/master/developersreference/developersreference/src/main/webapp/internationalization/labels.zul), and [properties file example](https://github.com/zkoss/zkbooks/blob/master/developersreference/developersreference/src/main/resources/metainfo/zk-label.properties) .

Comment: I already read through it and testet it out (see above). But now I am wondering:

multilines={
line 1
line 2
}

now I am wondering, do I have to write the "line" before my actual content I want in this line? that could be it

Comment: I have update the page with clear examples yesterday. Please read it again :)

Comment: if you write {line1 line2} in a properties file, please put the value in `<label multiline="true" />` to render it in multiple lines.